# wso2 esb sending payload from fault sequence

Tags: sequence, fault, payload, wso2-esb

We want to send payload from a fault sequence instead of soap fault.
We are able to log the message in the fault sequence but when we use respond ,the payload in not going as response.

Answer (score 1):

You can define fault sequence in WSO2 ESB and add relevant mediators within that fault sequence.

If you are adding respond mediator in somewhere in the proxy or sequence, it will stop the process in the ESB and will send the message/response which came to that mediator to the client.[1]

If you need to add respond mediator which will send the fault message, you can add that into fault sequence.

Sample Code:

```
<sequence name="faultSeq" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<log level="full">
    <property name="Message" value="===========This is error sequence========"/>
</log>
<respond/>
</sequence>
```

Message which comes to Error sequence will be logged via log mediator. Same message will be sent to client as the response.

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Respond+Mediator

Comment: We are doing the same but when we use respond the intended payload (logs fine before payload) doesnt go back but some earlier value of the body is getting returned to the caller

Comment: If you can add your configs, it will be better to understand the scenario and give recommendations upon that.